# Can I a wrap a GET request inside another GET request?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I may well be approaching this incorrectly, but what I'm trying to do is consume a GET request so I can manipulate the response into a format that I want.  I need to be able to launch this from a browser, so I thought about building another RESTful service for this purpose.

i.e. Service ABC returns a string using a GET request. I want to take that string, do some manipulation and return it. I still need to be able to launch from a browser, so what I'm planning is to create a RESTful service XYZ, where the GET request in XYZ launches a call to the GET request of ABC, takes that response, converts it into my collection, and returns that collection.  I'll then display in MVC.

Firstly: is this a dumb choice?  I don't know a lot about different types of services.

Secondly: I have been able to get the ABC service data using a Console client, but not using a web-based client or service.  Is this to be expected?

Code:

```
string webPath = @"http://ABCService.co.uk/";
string methodCall = @"methodABC/uid";
RestClient restClient = new RestClient(webPath);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(methodCall, Method.GET);
var restResponse = restClient.Execute(request);
var content = restResponse.Content;
```

This works fine in the console (and I've actually been able to get the data just using a WebClient too), but neither method works from inside an MVC controller or service.  I just get this as an ErrorException in restResponse:

> Exception: "{"Unable to connect to the remote server"  InnerException
>   = {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 80.64.52.36:80"}

Service ABC is up and running, can be accessed from a browser and console app.  Note that I have no ability to alter any settings within Service ABC.

Many thanks

Comment: Is it possible, that you get blocked by a Firewall?

Comment: I'm able to consume the GET request from a web app and a browser, so I don't think that is the case

Comment: You could use Fiddler to see what requests are sent in both cases, and compare them.

Comment: I tried that, but no difference.  I resolved the issue by setting the proxy to null, see below.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by setting the proxy to null, rather than using a default proxy.

```
public string ReadWebReport(string path)
    {
        string str = String.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create(path) as HttpWebRequest;
        Request.Method = "GET"; //Or PUT, DELETE, POST
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Request.Proxy = null; //<-- inserted line


        using (HttpWebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new Exception("The request did not complete successfully and returned status code " + Response.StatusCode);
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                str = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return str;
    }
```